# Select file from cloud to upload in browser?

Tags: macos, mac, dropbox, finder, google-drive

Is there any such extension or plugin available for macs that let you browse your cloud files and select them in finder without actually keeping a copy of these files on your computer.

For example, if I was on a website asking me to upload a profile picture. I would select the upload button, navigate to my google drive or dropbox files via the finder window and select the file I required.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that where cloud space can be mounted on your system like a remote hard drive, such that it can be accessed from the file selection dialogue box like any other file, this should already just work... except that the data will travel from the cloud to your system to the remote system; the remote system would not have authorization to access the file directly.